# Delete the last character of a file without out overwriting it?

Tags: java, json, file, text

Sort of like [Get/delete last character of file without loading into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220213/get-delete-last-character-of-file-without-loading-into-memory) but in java.

I'm working on a json parser in java where the file would always end in `}`, but in order to write more information into the json file, it must be removed.

The only ways I know of doing this either involves loading the entire file in memory or transferring all the data to a temporary file just to get rid of a single character, which would be impractical when working with very large files.

Comment: You can use RandomAccessFile... Read a buffer, modify it (replace '}' by white-space/' ') and write back... But, why wouldn't collect a number of files instead of one single file? This should simplify the process and, for example, you may parallelize the parsing easily...

Comment: I'm using the json file to store URLs, and slashes are not allowed in the file name